# How to prove each column vector $t^i$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$ satisfies $At^i = \lambda(t^i)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

> If we have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $A=T\Lambda T^{-1}$ for $T\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, how to prove that each column vector $t^i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that $At^i = \lambda(t^i)$?

I'm having trouble understanding how to prove that each element $t^i$ of $T$ is still an eigenvalue/vector pair of $A$. Thus saying that $(t^i, \lambda_i)$ is an eigenvalue and eigenvector pair since $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ but $t$ is a column vector of $T$ and is only $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Any help in proving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. We recommend users to use MathJax to show math expressions, here is the [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: $\boldsymbol {AT} = \boldsymbol {T\varLambda }$.

Comment: Will do, thank you for the link to MathJax, I will use that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

So $A$ and $T$ are both $n \times n$ matrices. Note that any eigenvalue/eigenvector pair $\vec{x}, \lambda$ must satisfy
$$
A \vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x} \quad (*)
$$
and so $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If you take $k$ such pairs $\left(\vec{t}_i, \lambda_i\right)_{i=1}^k$, each one satisfying an equation like $(*)$, you can unite all such equations into a matrix equation
$$
AT = T \Lambda,
$$
where $T = (t_1| \ldots| t_k)$ will be $n \times k$ and $\Lambda$ will be a diagonal matrix with diagonal values $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$.

When $k=n$ you can show $T$ is invertible, so you get
$$
A = T \Lambda T^{-1}
$$
as in your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. To clarify, since I am given $ A = T \Lambda T^{-1} $ I can multiply both sides by $ T^{-1} $ to get $ AT = T \Lambda $ for which each column vector of $ T $ is $ t^{i} $? And each iteration of $t^{i}$ would automatically satisfy $ A \vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x} $ ? I guess where I am getting confused is where it's not saying that $T_{i}$ satisfies the requirement but rather the column vectors of $T$

Comment: @mugiwaragirl yes, correct, every column vector of $T = [t_1|\ldots|t_n]$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ on the diagonal of $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=T\Lambda T^{-1}$$

Multiply $T$ on both sides from the right.

$$AT=T\Lambda$$

Look at the $i$ column or if it helps, multiply by $e_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard unit vector, there you can observe that

$$At^i = \lambda_i t^i$$

Comment: Thank you for the comment, where do you get $ AT = T \lambda $ from? Do you mean $ AT = T \Lambda $ ? Sorry if this is obvious but I am trying to understand. And did you multiply both sides by $ T $ or $T^{-1}$ ?

Comment: that was a typo, you are right. it is supposed to be $\Lambda$. I multiplied both sides by $T$ from the right.